# Why is my WHILE LOOP not stopping when I enter in my desired letters?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I am trying to produce a Python code where the user can only input the specific letters A, B, C, D, E and F. If they do not enter in these letters they are stuck in a WHILE loop till these letters are inputted. Now my issue is my code is just not working.

```
letter_group=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
question= input("Enter a letter? (A-F) ")

while question != any(letter_group):
  question=input("Error! Enter a letter? (A-F)")
else:
  question=str(question)
  
print(question)
```

The output of my code when inputting the my desired letters (A,B,C,D,E AND F) is not what I was expecting

```
Enter a letter? (A-F)  A
Error! Enter a letter? (A-F) B
Error! Enter a letter? (A-F) C
Error! Enter a letter? (A-F) D
Error! Enter a letter? (A-F) E
Error! Enter a letter? (A-F) F
```

How do I fix my code ?

Answer (score 1):

`any(letter_group)` is just checking if there are any letters in that group, and then you are comparing the boolean `True` value that that returns and comparing that to a string...

Just use `not in`

```
while question not in letter_group:
```